# How to apply random colors for array elements with pixmap?-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

I am creating a Pixmap for a class Block:

```
public Pixmap getPixmapCircle(int width, int height, Color color) {
    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    Pixmap.setBlending(Pixmap.Blending.None);
    pixmap.setColor(color);
    pixmap.fillCircle(60, 60, Constants.BLOCK_RADIUS);
    return pixmap;
}
```

creating texture:

```
public Texture getPixmapTexture(Color color){
    return new Texture(getPixmapCircle(125,125, color));
}
```

I have this array:

```
    private Array<Block> blocks = new Array<Block>();
```

Here I want to draw the block array as sprites like this:

```
 for (Block b : blocks){
        for (int i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++)
        blocksprite = new Sprite(block.getPixmapTexture(new 
   Color(0,5,.1f,1)));
        blocksprite.setPosition(b.getX()-blocksprite.getWidth()/2, b.getY()-
       blocksprite.getHeight()/2);
        blocksprite.draw(batch);
        }
```

Now I want to make a color array that contain 10 colors.
Color codes are given like this:

[image]
This array should be passed to getPixmapTexture() method,so that I should be able to apply random colors to the block sprites created.

I am confused of creating a color array,and applying random indices on the elements of block.

I tried with the hex color codes.Some colors are displaying.Some are not.
Why it is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libgdx Color class doesn't handle hex colors, but normalized rgba which means the values go from 0 to 1 (where 0 is 00 in hex and 1 is ff in hex), so to accopmlish what you want follow these steps:

1 - Convert each color to normalized rgb for example using [this tool](http://doc.instantreality.org/tools/color_calculator/)

2 - Create an array with the normalized colors, something like (the last number is alpha):

```
Color[] colorArray = {
    new Color(0.5f, 0.4f, 0.3f, 1),
    new Color(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.7f, 1),
    ...
};
```

3 - Randomize the color when creating the block:

```
Random random = new Random();

for (Block b : blocks){
    int index = random.nextInt(colorArray.length);
    blocksprite = new Sprite(block.getPixmapTexture(colorArray[index]));
    blocksprite.setPosition(b.getX()-blocksprite.getWidth()/2, b.getY() -blocksprite.getHeight()/2);
    blocksprite.draw(batch);
}
```